# Cisco 6500 vss mode upgrade

Tags: cisco, redundancy, vss

This is not my network. I'm trying to understand why my cloud provider insists that they need to take down both routers when performing updates.

From what I understand they have 2 Cisco 6500s clustered via VSS, active-active. When they perform an upgrade, they always take both down at the same time. My question is, why? Isn't the whole idea of this setup is so that you don't have to take them both down? Take one off-line, update/upgrade it, bring it back on-line, take the other off-line, update/upgrade it, bring it back on-line.

Where am I going off the rails with this? I pay for redundancy but don't seem to be getting it.

Thanks.

Comment: have you confirmed that they are running in stacked mode?

Comment: Can you give me more info on what stacked mode is?

Comment: vss means stacked to me, but maybe they never really had vss enabled and were just saying they did.  Just a guess.

Answer (score 1):

Although we've moved to Cisco Nexus's we have a lot of existing 65's and I've never come across a need to take down both routers in a VSS cluster, that's kind of the point - I think your instincts are correct and you need to get them to justify, in writing, why they insist on their behaviour - feel free to come back with this when/if they respond.

Comment: Like you say the point of VSS is so you don't have to take down both nodes at once.  Shank's SP either doesn't understand how to upgrade a VSS system, doesn't have him connected to the VSS correctly, or are lying to him about actually running a VSS.  I'm definitely interested to see what they say.